# How many Antisymmetric relations are possible on a set A?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, relations

> Let $A$ be a set with $|A| =5$. How many Antisymmetric relations are possible on set A whose size is maximum ?

---

As I started with small cases, the maximum size of antisymmetric relation that I got is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ which gives maximum size = 15

But, I am having a hard time to find out how many are there ?

Comment: I don't understand the 'whose size is maximum' ....

Comment: @Bram28 Anyone thinking a little can get it.

Comment: @Bram28 It is just a Maximum sized "Antisymmetric relation" on $A$ .

Comment: Hmm, I guess I must never have run into that term ... is it that if you have a maximum sized antisymmetric relation, it will no longer be antisymmetric when you add another pair to it?

Comment: @Bram28 Exactly .

Comment: Just look at binary matrices of size $|A|\times |A|$. A one means the pair is in the relation. Only a triangle of the matrix is needed to determine the relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So given that it is maximal, it will have all pairs $(a,a)$ with $a \in A$.

And of all pairs of different objects $a$ and $b$ it either has $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ in it, but not both.

There are 10 such pairs, so that means there are $2^{10}$ such possible maximum anti-symmetric relations.

Comment: Why it is not $3^{10}$.You can either take (a,b) or take (b,a) or don't take anyone of them?

Comment: @user3767495 It's because it's supposed to be of 'maximum' size. In the comments, I was able to have the OP clarify this as a set such that if you add any pair, it is no longer anti-symmetric.  As such, having neither $(a,b)$ nor $(b,a)$ in the set would mean it is not maximal, since you can add one of them. So: for it to be maximal, you need at least one of them, but for it to be anti-symmetric, you obviously can;t have. So, you need exactly one of the two.